# Rails form not reading form input

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Those are my first few days with Ruby on Rails and Im failing to create a page where you can read posts and post your own. 
I can't figure out why my input fields are not getting read.

notices/index.html.erb:

```
<% if @notices.any? %>
    <ol class="notices">
        <%= render @notices %>
    </ol>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @notice do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

    <%= f.label :content %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Message content" %>

<%= f.submit "Post" %>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
class NoticesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @notices = Notice.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 6)
    @notice = current_user.notices.new
  end

  def create
    @notices = Notice.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 6)
    @notice = current_user.notices.build(content: params[:content])
    if @notice.save
      flash[:success] = "Message posted!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'index'
    end
  end
```

In routes I have defined resources :notices

If I change @notice where content: "some string" my message is getting posted by a proper user with "some string" as a content. But if I try to pass content from my form validation against empty input launches.
Could you explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define:

```
notices_params
 params.require(:notice).permit(:content)
end
```

And then

```
@notice = current_user.notices.build(notices_params)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought your way is just a good practice and those two solutions are the same.
Can you tell me why it was not working?

Comment: You can check the params in the logs. It’s not params[:content]. It’s params[:notice][:content]. But it’s better to use strong params with require and permit.

Answer (score 1):

Just write in controller @notice = current_user.notices.all